# Числа Фибоначчи JS

Tags: javascript, числа-фибоначчи

Напишите функцию `fib(n)`, которая возвращает n-е число
Фибоначчи.
Пример работы:

```
function fib(n) { /* ваш код */ }
alert( fib(3) ); // 2
alert( fib(7) ); // 13
alert( fib(77)); // 5527939700884757
```

Вот решение :

```
function fib(n) {
    var a = 1,
    b = 1;
    for (var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        var c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
alert( fib(7) );
```

Не понимаю - почему `i = 3`, а не `1` и почему `return b`, а не `c`?

Comment: потому что первое и второе число - 1. в конце итерации значение `c` присваивается переменной `b`

Comment: 1. Потому что первые два числа Фибоначчи заданы по определению, остальные вычисляются. 2. Потому что если `n < 3`, то `return c` вернет `undefined`.

Comment: 1. потому что первые 2 числа это единицы и они не требуют вычисления. 2. потому что для первых двух случаев c не инициализировано, если бы перед циклом было написано `var c = 1;`, то можно было бы и `c` возвращать

Comment: Хорошо бы почитать про этот `феномен с числами` и его общий смысл.